# onPause doesn't called when another app gets focus

Tags: java, android

I'm learning android development with "Head First Android Development" by Dawn Griffiths.
In this book, it explains that onPause() method is called when another app comes to focus but still visible on the screen. But the code inside onPause method doesn't seem to be executed. I tested this with several apps' pop-up view. This is the code for my stopwatch app's mainActivity:

```
package com.hfad.stopwatch;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import java.util.Locale;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private int seconds = 0;
    private boolean running;
    private boolean wasRunning;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            seconds = savedInstanceState.getInt("seconds");
            running = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("running");
            wasRunning = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("wasRunning");
        }
        runTimer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        wasRunning = running;
        running = false;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (wasRunning) {
            running = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        savedInstanceState.putInt("seconds", seconds);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("running", running);
        savedInstanceState.putBoolean("wasRunning", wasRunning);
    }

    public void onClickStart(View view) {
        running = true;
    }

    public void onClickStop(View view) {
        running = false;
    }

    public void onClickReset(View view) {
        running = false;
        seconds = 0;
    }

    private void runTimer() {
        final TextView timeView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.time_view);
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        handler.post(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                int hours = seconds/3600;
                int minutes = (seconds%3600)/60;
                int secs = seconds%60;
                String time = String.format(Locale.getDefault(),
                        "%d:%02d:%02d", hours, minutes, secs);
                timeView.setText(time);
                if (running) {
                    seconds++;
                }
                handler.postDelayed(this, 1000);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

runTimer() method is the one for checking variables state every 1000 milliseconds to determine whether it increments 'seconds' variable when 'running' variable is true. Inside the onPause() method, it sets 'running' variable to false, which leads to stop the stopwatch. But when I execute some apps as pop-up view, it doesn't stop. It does stop when my stopwatch app goes to background (invisible). Can anyone else tell me what I'm missing about?